# ShapelyFeature.Reader not Working in Cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I am running the following simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader as shpreader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

fname = r'C:/cb_2018_us_cd116_500k.shp'

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(shpreader(fname).geometries(),
                                ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(shpreader(fname).geometries(),
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can someone help?

I'm running Python 3.6 in Pycharm on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shapereader as shpreader` is module, what you want is class present in that module i.e. [cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html#cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader)

```
shape_feature = ShapelyFeature(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries(),
                                ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='none')
```

Answer (score -1):

this library:

```
from cartopy.io import shapereader as shpreader
```

works for me

Try to change your directory

this: `fname = r'C:/cb_2018_us_cd116_500k.shp'`

for: `fname = 'C:user/yourname/cb_2018_us_cd116_500k.shp'`